# How to Combine Two Queries and Order Data Together

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes of different label types but properties that can be ordered. It looks something like this:

```
Node:Food
    property:2

Node2:Animal
    property:3

Node3:Animal
    property:1

Node4:Food
    property:4
```

I'd like to order them by the property. Meaning display all of the nodes by the order of the property (1-2-3-4).

I've tried doing it like this:

```
MATCH (m:Food)
RETURN m AS list ORDER BY m.property
UNION
MATCH (n:Animal)
RETURN n AS list ORDER BY n.property
```

But this results in the order being all of the Foods first, then the Animals.

Is there a way to combine both Node results together and order them by both of their properties?

All Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
CREATE (f1:Food {property: 2})
CREATE (a1:Animal {property: 3})
CREATE (a2:Animal {property: 1})
CREATE (f2:Food {property: 4})
```

Query

```
MATCH n
WHERE n:Animal OR n:Food
RETURN n
ORDER BY n.Property
```